# Wordpress migration to production url missing ":" from https://

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I just migrated my wordpress (5.4.2) from local to production. I changed my urls in my database. But when I try to access my domain https://www.example.com) I get redirected to : "http://https//example.com/wp-admin/"

My hosting service provider is OVH in France

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
# généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les 
filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: My guess is that you've missed the `:` somewhere when updating the URLs, which makes WP think it's part of the address and not the schema. That htaccess doesn't do anything regarding http vs https though.

Comment: That looks like a migration issue with trying to replace urls. I'd check your migration settings specifically whatever part has to do with changing environment urls. Either that or an issue with setting the WP_HOME constant. What is your WP_HOME constant set at on your localhost and on production? Were you using non-secure links on your localhost?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I used Migrate DB extension

Comment: @PhilF 

localhost : `http://localhost/acd`

production : `https://www.auxcrinsdor.com`

Comment: K, that looks correct for your WP_HOST constant. So I'd stick with Migrate DB as the most likely culprit right now. What were your Find and Replace fields for the migration?

Comment: It's odd that you're saying it's redirecting though. You're saying its a 301 status code? I wonder if you rename the index.php file to anything else just to test if it's the web server or WordPress that is doing the redirecting. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @PhilF In fact, I can access my wp-admin. When i rename index.php it keeps redireting to the wrong url but I don't know the status code.

Concerning the search and replace, it was :

`//localhost/acd` -> `//www.auxcrinsdor.com`
`C:\wamp64\www\acd` -> `\www`

Comment: K, I'd also add `http://www.auxcrinsdor.com` to `https://www.auxcrinsdor.com` to convert the non-https to https. I went to https://www.auxcrinsdor.com and it's not redirecting for me. Is it still doing it for you? If so, what is an example? Thanks,

Comment: Well, it seems to work now. I tried on my laptop too and it is working fine. It might be my browser's cache. Thank you for all